# How can I make a double loop faster in Python?

Tags: python

I have a code that starts from a dataframe 'DF_time' which is a column of 8760 values that are the date and time of a year as shown below and another datafrmae 'Forced' which consists of a series of rows with a time to start a certain process, the time to end and the loss involved, what I want is to know how much loss I have in each hour. I have made a loop but it takes a long time to execute and I don't know how to make it faster.

```
LOST= pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(DF_time)),columns = ['perd'])
LOST['DF_time'] = DF_time['datetime']

for j in range(0,len(DF_time)-1):
    HOUR= DF_time.loc[j,'datetime']
    for i in range(0,len(Forced)-1):
        data_star = Forced.loc[i,'Start']
        data_end = Forced.loc[i,'End']
        if (HOUR>=data_star) and (HOUR<=data_end):
            LOST.loc[j,('perd')]= LOST.loc[j,('perd')] + Forced.loc[i,'Lost']

DF_time
    datetime
0   2016-01-01 00:00:00
1   2016-01-01 01:00:00
2   2016-01-01 02:00:00
3   2016-01-01 03:00:00
4   2016-01-01 04:00:00
... ...
8779    2016-12-31 19:00:00
8780    2016-12-31 20:00:00
8781    2016-12-31 21:00:00
8782    2016-12-31 22:00:00
8783    2016-12-31 23:00:00



Forced
Start                End                Lost 
04/01/2016 4:00,    04/01/2016 8:30,    1.226829
22/01/2016 3:11,    22/01/2016 22:59,   1.226829
25/01/2016 3:00,    25/01/2016 3:15,    1.226829
01/06/2016 0:00,    02/06/2016 3:00,    1.226829
02/06/2016 3:00,    02/06/2016 6:00,    0.760081
```

As a result I get this:

```
    DF_time              perd
0   2016-01-01 00:00:00 10.437558
1   2016-01-01 01:00:00 10.437558
2   2016-01-01 02:00:00 10.437558
3   2016-01-01 03:00:00 10.437558
4   2016-01-01 04:00:00 10.437558
... ... ...
8779    2016-12-31 19:00:00 8.751880
8780    2016-12-31 20:00:00 8.751880
8781    2016-12-31 21:00:00 8.751880
8782    2016-12-31 22:00:00 8.751880
8783    2016-12-31 23:00:00 0.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to speed up a loop is to get rid of it.

If you transform the `forced` dataframe such that both start and end times are in the same column, but for the end times the loss values have a negative sign, you can then sort by date, upsample to an hourly timeseries and simply take the cumulative sum over the transformed loss values:

```py
import pandas as pd

forced = pd.DataFrame([['04/01/2016 4:00', '04/01/2016 8:30', 1.226829],
                       ['22/01/2016 3:11', '22/01/2016 22:59', 1.226829],
                       ['25/01/2016 3:00', '25/01/2016 3:15', 1.226829],
                       ['01/06/2016 0:00', '02/06/2016 3:00', 1.226829],
                       ['02/06/2016 3:00', '02/06/2016 6:00', 0.760081]],
                      columns=['Start', 'End', 'Lost'])

for col in ['Start', 'End']:
    forced[col] = pd.to_datetime(forced[col], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

ends = forced[['End']].copy()
ends['Lost'] = - forced['Lost']

forced.rename({'Start': 'Time'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
ends.rename({'End': 'Time'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

forced = pd.concat([forced[['Time', 'Lost']], ends])

forced.set_index('Time', drop=True, inplace=True)
forced.sort_index(inplace=True)

forced = forced.resample('1h').sum()
forced['Loss'] = forced['Lost'].cumsum()

print(forced)
```

```
                     Lost      Loss
Time                                   
2016-01-04 04:00:00  1.226829  1.226829
2016-01-04 05:00:00  0.000000  1.226829
2016-01-04 06:00:00  0.000000  1.226829
2016-01-04 07:00:00  0.000000  1.226829
2016-01-04 08:00:00 -1.226829  0.000000
...                       ...       ...
2016-06-02 02:00:00  0.000000  1.226829
2016-06-02 03:00:00 -0.466748  0.760081
2016-06-02 04:00:00  0.000000  0.760081
2016-06-02 05:00:00  0.000000  0.760081
2016-06-02 06:00:00 -0.760081  0.000000

[3603 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

## SOLUTION CODE

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
DF_time = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-12-31 23:00:00', freq='H')
})

Forced = pd.DataFrame({
    'Start': ['04/01/2016 4:00', '22/01/2016 3:11', '25/01/2016 3:00', '01/06/2016 0:00', '02/06/2016 3:00'],
    'End': ['04/01/2016 8:30', '22/01/2016 22:59', '25/01/2016 3:15', '02/06/2016 3:00', '02/06/2016 6:00'],
    'Lost': [1.226829, 1.226829, 1.226829, 1.226829, 0.760081]
})

# Convert Start and End columns to datetime
Forced['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(Forced['Start'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
Forced['End'] = pd.to_datetime(Forced['End'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

# Initialize LOST dataframe with zeros
LOST = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(DF_time)), columns=['perd'])
LOST['DF_time'] = DF_time['datetime']

# Calculate the loss efficiently
for i, row in Forced.iterrows():
    mask = (DF_time['datetime'] >= row['Start']) & (DF_time['datetime'] <= row['End'])
    LOST.loc[mask, 'perd'] += row['Lost']

print(LOST)
```

## Explanation:

The main difference between the two codes is the way they are looping over the dataframes. My code uses a `for` loop to iterate over the rows of the `Forced` dataframe, and for each row, it uses a mask to find the rows in the `DF_time` dataframe that fall within the time range of the current row in the `Forced` dataframe. This is a more efficient way of looping over the dataframes because it only needs to check each row in the `DF_time` dataframe once, regardless of how many rows match the time range of the current row in the `Forced` dataframe.

In your code, on the other hand, there is a nested `for` loop to iterate over both the rows of the `Forced` dataframe and the rows of the `DF_time` dataframe. So there is an exponential computation time.